# Can I prevent one part of a multifunction USB device from being installed when connected?

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers

I have a PS4 gamepad (Dualshock 4) that I'm using over a wired connection.  Each time I plug it in, it presents one gamepad device, and two audio devices (input/output).  Each time this happens, the Windows default sound output changes from my laptop speakers to the gamepad audio output, even though the headphone jack on the device isn't connected to anything.

I've tried disabling the added audio devices in Device Manager, but even though they appear disabled, they still show up in the output device selection list and still take over the default when disconnected and reconnected.  I can "Uninstall Device", but then as soon as I plug the gamepad in the next time, they show up again.

I'm on Windows 10 Home, so I don't have access to the Group Policy editor, but I thought there might be a registry key where I could blacklist a USB device by class GUID or something. I would welcome other creative approaches.

ETA: In case it matters, the structure in Device Manager is:

- USB Composite device (`VID_054c&PID_09cc`)

  - USB Input Device (`VID_054c&PID_09cc&MI_03`)

    - HID-compliant game controller (same?)
  - Wireless Controller (`VID_054c&PID_09cc&MI_00`)

    - Headset Earphone
    - Headset Microphone

If there are any useful identifiers on the earphone/microphone, I don't know which ones to look for.  I'd like to disable "wireless controller" and its children.

Comment: Yes; You can block specific USB devices;  You have not provided enough information to determine if you can blocked the audio functionality of the device though

Comment: What other information is needed, @Ramhound?  I'm not really sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: In your case all the devices actually have the same device ID